# How to group a list of tuples sorted by first element into two lists containing overlapping and non overlapping tuples

Tags: scala

I have a sorted list of tuples (sorted by first element) say for eg.
[(1, 6)
(5, 9)
(6, 8)
(11, 12)
(16, 19)]

I need to split the list into a list of overlapping and a list of non overlapping tuples. So the output for the above list would be

overlapping: [(1, 6), (5, 9), (6, 8)] 
non overlapping: [(11, 12), (16, 19)]

I am trying to use foldLeft but not sure if it's possible that way

```
.foldLeft(List[(Long, Long)]()){(list, tuple) => list match {
    case Nil => List(tuple)
    case head :: tail => if (head.2 >= tuple._1) {
     // Not sure what should my logic be
    } else {
      // Not sure
    }
}}
```

Input: [(1, 6) (5, 9) (6, 8) (11, 12) (16, 19)]
Output: [(1, 6), (5, 9), (6, 8)] and [(11, 12), (16, 19)]

Comment: This problem is underdefined. For example, what do you do with `Seq((1,3), (2, 5), (6, 8), (7, 9))`? First two and last two overlap, but second and third do not ... So, second and third tuples here are _both_  "overlapping" and "non-overlappign". Also, what are constraints on the second element of the tuples? You seem to assume, it is always larger than the first ...

Comment: Do you need order in output?

Comment: @Dima For the example you mentioned overlapping would be the entire Seq and non overlapping would be empty.

Comment: @Dima If any two tuples are overlapping then both of them will go under overlapping list. Only those tuples/ranges that are not overlapping with any of the other tuples will go to non overlapping list

Comment: @Dima Yes the first element is always less than second element of the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've understood. You want to find each tuple, in the input, whom `Long`s are consecutive bounds of a range (so I can use `Range` by the way) and that range doesn't contain any `Long` from another tuple in the input.

Here's my suggestion:

```
  Seq((1L, 6L), (5L, 9L), (6L, 8L), (11L, 12L), (16L, 19L))
    .map { case (start, end) => start to end }
    .foldLeft(Set[(Long, Long)]() -> Set[(Long, Long)]()) {
      case ((overlapping, nonoverlapping), range) =>
        (overlapping ++ nonoverlapping).find { case (start, end) =>
          range.contains(start) || range.contains(end) || (start to end).containsSlice(range)
        }.fold(overlapping -> (nonoverlapping + (range.start -> range.end)))(matchedTuple =>
          (overlapping + (matchedTuple, range.start -> range.end), nonoverlapping - matchedTuple)
        )
    }
```

It may not work for tuples like `(6, 6)` or `(10, 0)` because they're computed as empty ranges and you have to decide limit cases with empty ranges like them if you want to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that, first element is always less than second element of the tuple. Order doesn't matter but the input is always sorted by first element

Comment: Well thank you, but I think you mentioned it in the title so no trouble I guess... Do you mean the output must be sorted?

Comment: No I said nothing about the output, input would be a list of tuples sorted by their first elements. From the example I provided (1L, 6L), (5L, 9L), (6L, 8L), (11L, 12L), (16L, 19L), so as you can see 1, 5, 6, 11, 16 are in sorted fashion. So output two lists one having overlapping tuples and other having non overlapping tuples. Overlapping as in take any tuple and make sure it doesn't overlap with any of the other tuple in the input list. From the input only (11, 12) and (16, 19) are not overlapping with any other tuples from the list

Comment: Well... It seems pretty clear to me. Let me know if I can do something else for your problem. But although my solution could be perfectible, I do think it works.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dima that this question is unclear.  It's important to note that the approach above will also fail because you return a single list, not one list of overlapping intervals and one of non-overlapping intervals.
A possible approach to this problem -- especially if you're set on using foldLeft -- would be to do something like this:

```
ls.foldLeft((List[(Int, Int)](), List[(Int, Int)]()))((a, b) => (a, b) match {
case ((Nil, _), (h1, t1)) => (a._1 ::: List((h1, t1)), a._2)
case ((head :: tail, _), (h2, t2)) if head._2 >= h2 => (a._1 ::: List((h2, t2)), a._2)
case ((head :: tail, _), (h2, t2)) => (a._1, a._2 ::: List((h2, t2)))
})
```

Of course, if we don't address the problem of having several non-overlapping subsets of overlapping intervals, this solution also fails.

Comment: Your code returns (List[(Int, Int)], List[(Int, Int)]) = (List((1,6), (5,9), (6,8)),List((11,12), (11,15), (16,10)))  
but it should be (List[(Int, Int)], List[(Int, Int)]) = 
(List((1,6), (5,9), (6,8), (11,12), (11,15)), List((16,10)))

Any tuple that overlaps with any of the other from the input should be added to overlapping and rest should be added to non overlapping

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, find overlapping ones first, and then compute the rest. This will do it in linear time.

```
 @tailrec
 def findOverlaps(
   ls: List[(Int, Int)],
   boundary: Int = Int.MinValue, 
   out: List[(Int, Int)] = Nil
 ): List[(Int, Int)] = ls match {
   case (a, b) :: tail if a < boundary => 
     findOverlaps(tail, b max boundary, (a, b) :: out)
   case _ :: Nil | Nil => out.reverse
   case (a, b) :: (c, d) :: tail if b > c => 
     findOverlaps(ls.tail, b max boundary, (a, b) :: out)
   case _ :: tail  => findOverlaps(tail, boundary, out)
 }  

 val overlaps = findOverlasp(ls)
 val nonOverlaps = ls.filterNot(overlaps.toSet)
```